# Find a specific substring using Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pull a specific substring from a string of the form:

```
foo=abc;bar=def;baz=ghi
```

For example, how would I get the value of "bar" from that string?

Comment: is the string a row value or something passed in?

Comment: do you have any say in the db schema? storing values like that goes against how sql databases are supposed to work.

Comment: I agree. I would not have designed it this way, but I'm having to work with existing code.

Comment: what version of SQL ? if 2005/8 sounds like a good job for a clr function.

Comment: It makes a big difference what you want to use it for. I can't believe all the answers provided without even knowing whether your're selecting with it, or displaying it, or using it in a subquery, or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) and [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).  For example, to search for the value of "baz":

```
declare @str varchar(128)
set @str = 'foo=abc;bar=def;baz=ghi'

-- Make sure @str starts and ends with a ;
set @str = ';' + @str + ';'

select substring(@str, 
    charindex(';baz=',@str) + len(';baz='),
    charindex('=',@str,charindex(';baz=',@str)) - charindex(';baz=',@str) - 1)
```

Or for the value of "foo" at the start of the string:

```
select substring(@str, 
    charindex(';foo=',@str) + len(';foo='),
    charindex('=',@str,charindex(';foo=',@str)) - charindex(';foo=',@str) - 1)
```

Here's a UDF to accomplish this (more readable version inspired by BlackTigerX's answer):

```
create function dbo.FindValueInString(
    @search varchar(256),
    @name varchar(30))
returns varchar(30)
as
begin
    declare @name_start int
    declare @name_length int
    declare @value_start int
    declare @value_end int

    set @search = ';' + @search

    set @name_start = charindex(';' + @name + '=',@search)
    if @name_start = 0
        return NULL

    set @name_length = len(';' + @name + '=')
    set @value_start = @name_start + @name_length
    set @value_end = charindex(';', @search, @value_start)

    return substring(@search, @value_start, @value_end - @value_start)
end
```

As you can see, this isn't easy in Sql Server :)  Better do this in the client language, or normalize your database so the substrings go in their own columns.

Comment: I should mention, though, that "bar" could just as easily be at the beginning or end of this string. I don't think your solution accounts for that.

Comment: The solution is lengthy, but it should work?  Even right now. :)

Comment: It works as long as you pad the beginning of @str with a ';'. Fix it accommodate potentially not having a leading ';' and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Added the leading character and UDF included now

Comment: To your credit, I do realize that this is terrible to do in Transact-SQL, but, at this point, I don't see a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a generalized solution that works for this problem:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_StringBetween]
(
    @BaseString varchar(max),
    @StringDelim1 varchar(max),
    @StringDelim2 varchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @at1 int
    DECLARE @at2 int
    DECLARE @rtrn varchar(max)

    SET @at1 = CHARINDEX(@StringDelim1, @BaseString)
    IF @at1 > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @rtrn = SUBSTRING(@BaseString, @at1
         + LEN(@StringDelim1), LEN(@BaseString) - @at1)
        SET @at2 = CHARINDEX(@StringDelim2, @rtrn)
        IF @at2 > 0
            SET @rtrn = LEFT(@rtrn, @at2 - 1)
    END

    RETURN @rtrn
END
```

so if you run (just wrap your original string to be searched with ';' at beginning and end):

```
PRINT dbo.fn_StringBetween(';foo=abc;bar=def;baz=ghi;', ';bar=', ';')
```

you will get 'def' returned.

Answer (score 0):

look into the PATINDEX function.  It has wildcard matching which should help you..

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
alter function FindValue(@txt varchar(200), @find varchar(200)) 
returns varchar(200)
as
begin
declare 
    @firstPos int,
    @lastPos int

select @firstPos = charindex(@find, @txt), @lastPos = charindex(';', @txt, @firstPos+5)

select @lastPos = len(@txt)+1 where @lastPos = 0

return substring(@txt, @firstPos+len(@find)+1, @lastPos-@firstPos-len(@find)-1)
end


select dbo.FindValue('foo=abc;bar=def;baz=ghi', 'bar')
```

update: was not using the length of @find

Answer (score 0):

this is assuming that the string will have the same string format just substitute the column name for the 'foo=abc;bar=def;baz=ghi'

```
select substring('foo=abc;bar=def;baz=ghi',patindex('%bar=%','foo=abc;bar=def;baz=ghi')+4, len('foo=abc;bar=def;baz=ghi')-patindex('%;baz=%','foo=abc;bar=def;baz=ghi')-4)
```

Answer (score -1):

This can achieve in simple way

```
DECLARE  @str VARCHAR(30)

DECLARE  @start INT

SET @str='foo=abc;bar=def;baz=ghi'

SET @start=CHARINDEX('bar',@str)

PRINT SUBSTRING(@str,@start,3)
```